# Upload image in web2py to database from default controller following image blog example

Tags: python, html, web2py

I'm following [this example](http://www.web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/03/overview#An-image-blog) to try and implement a way of uploading images from the default page of my application in web2py into the database. I went through the whole thing and can now view the images on the default page that were uploaded through the appadmin controller and the function /insert/db/image

What I would like is to have a small section on the default page to upload images from rather than having to go to a different page in /appadmin/insert/db/image

How would I implement this in the default controller and view? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply add a `SQLFORM` to the index page:

```
def index():
    [your existing code]
    form = SQLFORM(db.image).process()
    return dict(..., form=form)
```

In /views/default/index.html, wherever you want the form, add:

```
{{=form}}
```

Alternatively, you can use a grid, which provides an entire interface for listing, creating, and editing database records. You would replace the `form` lines above with:

```
grid = SQLFORM.grid(db.image)
return dict(..., grid=grid)
```

and:

```
{{=grid}}
```

Note, by default, all grid URLs are signed, so to create/edit/delete records, the user must be logged in (to disable this protection, set `user_signature=False`).

This is all covered in the [forms chapter](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/07/forms-and-validators).